# how to resolve use of operators in type declaration (Repa) ?

Tags: haskell, repa

I am playing around with Repa, and the code below can compile and run.

```
import qualified Data.Array.Repa as R
--t:: R.Array R.U (R.Z R.:. Int) Float 
--t =  R.fromListUnboxed (R.Z R.:. (10::Int)) ([1.0..10]::[Float])

main = do 
   let x = R.fromListUnboxed (R.Z R.:. (10::Int)) ([1.0..10]::[Float])
   print x
```

I believe (from check in ghci) that x has the type signature that I have declared t to have, but I get this error if I uncomment everything associated with t:

```
Illegal operator ‘R.:.’ in type ‘R.Z R.:. Int’
  Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types
```

what is the correct way to resolve the use of an type operator/constructor in type declarations? (I will google some more, but would like to ask anyway too learn more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command line option `-XTypeOperators` to either ghc or ghci, e.g.:

```
ghci -XTypeOperators ...
```

Or you can use the OPTIONS_GHC pragma in your source file:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XTypeOperators #-}
```

<strike>I'm not sure why `LANGUAGE TypeOperators` is not recognized.</strike>

or the LANGUAGE pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

(make sure to spell it correctly.)

In this case the type of `t` is inferable, so you can use `:t` in ghci:

```
$ ghci
Prelude> import qualified Data.Array.Repa as R
Prelude R> let t =  R.fromListUnboxed (R.Z R.:. (10::Int)) ([1.0..10]::[Float])
Prelude R> :t t
t :: R.Array R.U (R.Z R.:. Int) Float
```

Note: I'm using GHC 7.10.2.

Comment: thanks. I worked just adding the language pragma. Got some ideas about literature to read to understand why this is necessary to add?

Comment: Here's a good place to start: [24 Days of GHC Extensions - Type Operators](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-08-type-operators.html)