# Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘-’ (and other errors while reversing a list)

Tags: haskell

I'm working through the "Seven Languages In Seven Weeks" book, and one of the questions in the first day of Haskell is to "*Write a function that takes a list and returns the same list in reverse*".

My first implementation worked fine:

```
reverseList :: [a] -> [a]
reverseList [] = []
reverseList [x] = [x]
reverseList (h:t) = reverseList(t) ++ [h]
```

I then thought of another approach, which I tried to implement as:

```
reverseList1 :: [a] -> [a]
reverseList1 [] = []
reverseList1 [x] = [x]
reverseList1 l = last(l) :: reverseList1(take(length(l)-1)(l))
```

(That is - take the last element, then append to it the reversed first-all-but-one elements). However, this gave me an error (actually, three) when I tried to load the file:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Day1             ( day1.hs, interpreted )

day1.hs:35:49: error: Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘-’
   |
35 |   reverseList1 l = last(l) :: reverseList1(take(length(l)-1)(l))
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^

day1.hs:35:49: error:
    Illegal operator ‘-’ in type ‘length (l) - 1’
      Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types
   |
35 |   reverseList1 l = last(l) :: reverseList1(take(length(l)-1)(l))
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^

day1.hs:35:59: error:
    Illegal type: ‘1’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
   |
35 |   reverseList1 l = last(l) :: reverseList1(take(length(l)-1)(l))
   |                                                           ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

---

Googling for the "not in scope" error suggested that I'm trying to use something which hasn't been imported - I don't *think* that I need to explicitly import "subtract", based on other experiments.

I don't understand the second error (`Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types`) - I see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566889/how-to-resolve-use-of-operators-in-type-declaration-repa) that `TypeOperators` is a flag I can set on `ghci`, but I'm not *trying* to use an operator in a type - `length(l)-1` is (to the best of my knowledge) an argument to `take`, not a type.

Googling "perhaps you intended to use DataTypes" led me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714435/haskell-again-illegal-types) - I *hope* that my code won't be as ripped-apart as that example, but it's possible that I'm equally clueless!

---

Based on the last example [here](https://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/pl2011/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node70.html), I also tried:

```
reverseList1 l = last(l) :: reverseList1(take(takeLength)(l))
  where takeLength = length(l)-1
```

(which gave a (very lengthy!) error starting with "Couldn't match type 'a'") and

```
reverseList1 l =
  let takeLength = length(l)-1 in
  in last(l) :: reverseList1(take(takeLength)(l))
```

Which gave

```
day1.hs:40:5: error: parse error on input ‘in’
   |
40 |     in last(l) :: reverseList1(take(takeLength)(l))
   |     ^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: The list constructor is `:`, not `::`. You've also written `in` twice in your second attempt.

Comment: Sidenote: Haskell functions are called like `func arg1 arg2 arg3 ...`. Calling them like `func(arg1)` is bad style and will likely cause problems later.

Comment: Writing `in` twice was intentional (though, I will admit, unintuitive!) since there are two "ins" in the example at the bottom of [here](https://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/pl2011/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node70.html). I'll try with just one - thanks! And yes - that was certainly a simple typo (`:`/`::`) that I missed, thank you!

I've certainly noticed that style, and I've usually tried to match it, but I put in the parentheses to make sure I was clear about what was calling what. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists are constructed with `:`. `::` denotes a type, and so Haskell tries to read it as a type, hence the error.

The corrected code is:

```
reverseList1 :: [a] -> [a]
reverseList1 [] = []
reverseList1 [x] = [x]
reverseList1 l = last l : reverseList1 (take (length l - 1) l)
```

Note the bracketing that makes the code more readable!

In your second attempt, you write `in` twice and the parser gets confused.

The corrected code is:

```
reverseList1 l =
  let takeLength = length l - 1
  in last l : reverseList1 (take takeLength) l
```

---

Now, the error is actually quite interesting. The `TypeOperators` extension is one that allows (unsurprisingly) infix operators in type declarations.

Here, the compiler noticed that `-` looked like an infix operator, and given that it was in a type signaures inferred that you probably meant to use the `TypeOperators` extension. Of course, that wasn't the case here!

As for `DataKinds`, that is a fairly advanced extension that allows you to put data (like `1`, `"Hello"` etc.) in types. I won't go into exactly what it's used for here, but the reason that the compiler mentioned it is that you used `1` in a type signature, which can only be used with the `DataKinds` extension.

Comment: Thank you very much! Amazing how much difference an extra colon can make to how the compiler interprets commands :)

Comment: @scubbo Much like a stray semicolon, one might say ;)