# Typo(?) ("composition") in Seven Languages In Seven Weeks - Haskell Section

Tags: haskell

I'm [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798038/not-in-scope-type-constructor-or-class-and-other-errors-while-reversing-a/52798068?noredirect=1#comment92515991_52798068) working through "Seven Languages In Seven Weeks", and I've either found a typo or something that I don't understand.

One of the challenges reads:

> Write a function that takes an argument `x` and returns a lazy sequence that has every third number, starting with `x`. Then, write a function that includes every fifth number, beginning with `y`. Combine these functions *through composition* to return every eighth number, beginning with `x+y`

(Emphasis mine)

It's the "composition" that I'm not sure about. Judging by previous parts of the book, composition is carried out via the `.` operator and, from earlier in the book, is defined as

> a process that used the return from one function as the input of another

Given that definition, I don't see how composition would achieve what's described here, since the output of each of the described functions is an `[Int]`, but their inputs are `Int`. My implementation (*not* using composition) is below:

```
lazy3rd :: Int -> [Int]
lazy3rd x = x:(lazy3rd (x+3))
lazy5th :: Int -> [Int]
lazy5th x = x:(lazy5th (x+5))
lazy8th :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
lazy8th x y = zipWith (+) (lazy3rd x) (lazy5th y)
----
[in Prelude]
Prelude> take 9 (Day2.lazy8th 4 6)
[10,18,26,34,42,50,58,66,74]
```

Looking [here](https://pragprog.com/titles/btlang/errata) (search for `#82151`), it seems I'm not alone in being confused.

Comment: Probably, the book is using the term _composition_ rather liberally here, without referring to `(.)`. It's only saying "use A and B to achieve C".

Comment: If the usage of "composition" there was literal why giving it as an exercise? I mean it would literally be saying "Insert the ASCII character `.` between the name of these two functions" which does not sound like an interesting exercise. It's probably a shorthand for "write a function `f`, whose implementation uses a call to one of the two functions you just defined to obtain a value that is, maybe after some other operation, fed to other function such that...". It's simply saying "do this exercise but use the two functions you just defined, don't do it from scratch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the book just gives a practice for writing the pointfree style. So even if you don't know the common combinatory pattern suggested by @Will Ness, you can transform any expression into a pointfree style.
Remember the fact that if a parameter `x` is located at the end of both the function definition and the function body, you can eliminate it, such as:

`fun x = <some function body> $ x`

can be rewritten as

`fun = <some function body>`

So, the key for transformation is moving the parameter `x` at the end of the function definition to the end of the definition body, and can be written in the form of `<some function body> $ x`, which is important.

In your case, `lazy8th x y = zipWith (+) (lazy3rd x) (lazy5th y)` is easy to get. So now the first step is moving `y` to the end of the definition body, since `y` is at the end of the left side. This step is easy:

`lazy8th x y = zipWith (+) (lazy3rd x) (lazy5th y)`

=> `lazy8th x y = zipWith (+) (lazy3rd x) . lazy5th $ y`

with which we can eliminate the parameter `y` at the end, and get:

`lazy8th x = zipWith (+) (lazy3rd x) . lazy5th`

Next we need to remove the `x`, but how? It is not as obvious as `y`.

To solve it, we need to remember one common skill in Haskell —— **Section** for the partial application, such as `x + y` => `(+ y) x`. With this concept in mind, we can change the previous result as follows:

`lazy8th x = zipWith (+) (lazy3rd x) . lazy5th`

=> `lazy8th x = (. lazy5th) (zipWith (+) (lazy3rd x))`

`(.)` is just a binary operator like `(+)`, remember?

Now since the parameter `x` is at the end of the definition body, we can rewrite it into:

`lazy8th x = (. lazy5th) (zipWith (+) . lazy3rd $ x)`

However, `x` is not at the end of the whole body. It is easy to achieve this. Remember that `(. lazy5th) (zipWith (+) . lazy3rd $ x)` is just `f1 (f2 $ x)`, which can be transformed into `f1 . f2 $ x` easily. So the final result is obvious:

`lazy8th x = (. lazy5th) (zipWith (+) . lazy3rd $ x)`

=> `lazy8th x = (. lazy5th) . (zipWith (+) . lazy3rd) $ x`

=> `lazy8th = (. lazy5th) . (zipWith (+) . lazy3rd)`

=> `lazy8th = (. lazy5th) . zipWith (+) . lazy3rd`

since `(.)` associates to the right (and is associative, in general). This is the final pointfree style definition.

Comment: Thanks for the guide on how to derive this! It's fascinating how you and Mark came to this same conclusion by different means - his appears to be guided by Type signatures and yours by application of identities. For what it's worth, I really doubt that this was the route that the book intended, since it hasn't yet mentioned pointfree style or the `$` operator (though I've seen the latter while researching online). But your series of steps was very instructive, thank you!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it gives a walkthrough of *how* to get from the naive implementation to the composed one - but I highly recommend reading Mark's answer that goes into more detail on the type signatures involved.

Answer (score 3):

I don't feel convinced that the following is what the author of that question had in mind, but you can write `lazy8th` like this:

```
lazy8th = (. lazy5th) . zipWith (+) . lazy3rd
```

How does this work? Let's break it down, but let's start by reiterating the type of the composition operator:

```
Prelude> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

To describe it in words, the `.` operator is a function that takes a function from `b` to `c`, and another function from `a` to `b`, and composes them by 'gluing' them together on `b`, to produce a composed function from `a` to `c`.

## First step

Which type does `(. lazy5th)` have, then?

```
Prelude> :t (. lazy5th)
(. lazy5th) :: ([Int] -> c) -> Int -> c
```

The `lazy5th` function has the declared type `Int -> [Int]`, and it 'sits' in the position of `a -> b` in the type of `.`. In other words, `a` must be `Int`, and `b` must be `[Int]`.

Since the function is only partially applied, it's still waiting for the left function, which should have the type `b -> c`. We've just learned that `b` is `[Int]`, so the function this partially applied expression is still 'waiting for' must have the type `[Int] -> c`. Once we supply such a function, we get a function `a -> c`, or rather, replacing `a` with `Int`, `Int -> c`.

## Second step

What type does `zipWith (+)` have?

```
Prelude> :t zipWith (+)
zipWith (+) :: Num c => [c] -> [c] -> [c]
```

Given the definition of `zipWith`, this is hardly surprising, I hope.

What, then, is the type of `(. lazy5th) . zipWith (+)`?

```
Prelude> :t (. lazy5th) . zipWith (+)
(. lazy5th) . zipWith (+) :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
```

How do we get there? Let's recapitulate what we knew:

```
Prelude> :t (. lazy5th)
(. lazy5th) :: ([Int] -> c) -> Int -> c
Prelude> :t zipWith (+)
zipWith (+) :: Num c => [c] -> [c] -> [c]
```

How does `[c] -> [c] -> [c]` fit into the mold of `a -> b`? It does once we realise that, due to currying, `[c] -> [c] -> [c]` can also be written as `[c] -> ([c] -> [c])`. In other words, we can think of this function as a function that takes a single list `[c]` as input, and returns a function `[c] -> [c]` as output. Thus, replacing `a` with `[c]`, and `b` with `[c] -> [c]`, this fits with the type of `(. lazy5th)`.

The input type of `(. lazy5th)` is `[Int] -> c`. Careful, now, because this `c` isn't the same `c` as in the previous paragraph, so let's call it `c'`: `[Int] -> c'`.

The only way `[c] -> [c]` can fit with `[Int] -> c'` is if `c` is `Int`, and `c'` is `[Int]`. Thus, the types so far, with helpful brackets:

```
(. lazy5th) :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int -> [Int]
zipWith (+) :: [Int] -> ([Int] -> [Int])
```

Thus, the composition of these two functions is a function that takes the input of `zipWith (+)` (`[Int]`) and passes the output as input to `(. lazy5th)`, which produces a function of the type `Int -> [Int]`.

## Third step

What's the type of `lazy3rd`?

```
Prelude> :t lazy3rd
lazy3rd :: Int -> [Int]
```

That's the declared type of the function, so no surprises there. How does that compose with the previous step?

Again, due to currying, we can rewrite `[Int] -> Int -> [Int]` as `[Int] -> (Int -> [Int])`. Now we have:

```
(. lazy5th) . zipWith (+) :: [Int] -> (Int -> [Int])
lazy3rd :: Int -> [Int]
```

Thus, the composition of these two expressions take the input to `lazy3rd`, which is `Int`, and returns a function of the type `(Int -> [Int])`:

```
Prelude> :t (. lazy5th) . zipWith (+) . lazy3rd
(. lazy5th) . zipWith (+) . lazy3rd :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

Alternatively, if brackets help, you could write it as:

```
(. lazy5th) . zipWith (+) . lazy3rd :: Int -> (Int -> [Int])
```

This means the same, though.

## Demo

Does it work, then?

```
Prelude> lazy8th = (. lazy5th) . zipWith (+) . lazy3rd
Prelude> take 9 $ lazy8th 4 6
[10,18,26,34,42,50,58,66,74]
```

Yes, it does.

## But how?

How did I come up with this solution?

Honestly, I cheated. I just typed `\x y -> zipWith (+) (lazy3rd x) (lazy5th y)` into [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/), and it gave me the result.

The exegesis and explanations, however, are my own.

Comment: Upvoted for the exegesis, even if this is likely not what the book intended.

Comment: for *any* `f` and `gh`, `((. f) . gh) x y = (. f) (gh x) y = (gh x . f) y = gh x (f y)`. it's a common combinatory pattern. they are all equivalent. so if one of them is well typed, all are. i.e. there's no need to bother with the specific interim expressions' types.

Comment: Wow - that's a lot of information and explanation, thank you! It's probably going to take me a few reads to fully grok this, but I really appreciate the walkthrough.